# Facebook Comments Plugin: disabling "other login providers" doesn't work

Tags: facebook, authentication, comments

On the Facebook Comments plugin, under Settings | Other Login Providers, I have unchecked "Allow users to post using other login providers."  However, if I log out of Facebook and land on the page with my plugin, the "comment using..." dropdown still appears.

This seems to be a new behavior -- I didn't notice it last week.  Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Bug status on FB can be found

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/392714937430332/

Temporary fix is to create new app all together .